# Apache: Remove "www." and redirect to sub directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

On my web server I have installed Wordpress to a sub folder `/wp`.
Now I want to use Apache's mod_rewrite to achieve the following:

1. Redirect all `www.domain.com` traffic to `domain.com`
2. Redirect all traffic to the sub folder `/wp`

I tried the following in my root's `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain\.com/ [R=permanent,L]
```

But that does not really work as intended.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: I have solved the first requirement by changing the latter two lines to:

```
# Redirect www.domain.com to domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://domain.com/$0 [R=301,L]
```

The second requirement is still open though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this additional rule:

```
RewriteRule (?!^wp/)^(.*)$ /wp/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.